# list with arrow right

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

i must make the list group like this without using Bootstrap:

[image]

It's easier to make thing like this with Bootstrap but my mentor force me not to use Bootstrap so is there anyway to make thing like this without Bootstrap?

Comment: What you tried in this /

Comment: FontAwesome is a pretty good resource for icons.